# Jquery not working in Master Page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, master-pages

When I run the following code, i get the error **Unexpected character '$'**

It runs sucessfully when I run it indvidually but when i run it via Master page it doesnt. Here's my Master Page code:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs"
    Inherits="SwordBugTrackingSystem.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head runat="server">
  <title></title>
  <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" runat="server">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/cal.js" runat="server" ></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
      $('input.one').simpleDatepicker();
    });
  </script>

  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">   
  </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

</head>
```

Here is my aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Title="About Us" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" 
    AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="About.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="SwordBugTrackingSystem.About" %>
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
  <h2>
      About
  </h2>
  <p>Some test inputs, each with a different setup:</p>
  <p><input class="one" type="text" name="date" value="" runat="server"/>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have client side script marked as runat="server", asp.net will try and compile it as c#/vb or whatever language your page is set to. Remove it and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would check to see is if the relative path is correct for jQuery.

If your Site.css stylesheet is loading properly then you probably need to reference the jQuery file with the tilde `~/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js`